# React-application in Kubernetes with nodejs and mysql

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx, kubernetes, microservices

I setup my React application with a NodeJS backend and MySQl as Database. Now I have 3 pod : frontend, backend and MySQL. The React application uses a proxy defined in **package.json** to communicate with the NodeJs backend. It works, now i would delete the proxy pass in package.json and create 2 backend, 1 to execute GET request and 1 to execute POST request. I have seen that i should create nginx deployment but it dosen't work.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: frontend
 labels:
   app: frontend
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: frontend
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: frontend
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: react-frontend
       image: frontapp
       ports:
       - containerPort: 3000
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: react-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: frontend
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    port: 3000  
    targetPort: 3000
  type: ClusterIP
```

### backend

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: backend
 labels:
   app: backend
spec:
 replicas: 1
 selector:
   matchLabels:
     app: backend
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: backend
   spec:
     containers:
     - name: app-backend
       image: serverapp
       ports:
       - containerPort: 3001
       env:
       - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
         value: mysql-service
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
 name: server-service
 labels:
   app: backend
spec:
 type: ClusterIP
 selector:
   app: backend
 ports:
 - port: 3001
   targetPort: 3001
```

For ngnix i create a folder called ngnix and i create a default.conf

```
upstream server-service{
     server server-service:3001;
}
upstream react-service {
  server react-service:3000;
}

server {
    listen       80;
   
    location / {
         proxy_pass http://react-service;
    }


    location /insert {
        proxy_pass http://server-service;
    }
    location /get {
        proxy_pass http://server-service;
    }
}
```

and my Dockerfile is that

```
FROM nginx
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/conf.d
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
```

my file yaml for nginx

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: ngapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: I don't see any service exposing the nginx deployment, do you have one?

Comment: I forgot to create it! When i will create the service i should put this on package.json of the react Application?

Comment: I would put it in an environment variable that you pass to the frontend deployment, (the same way that you did with MYSQL_DATABASE), it helps to understand the communication flow without having to go inside the container. But it would work in the package.json as well.

Comment: thanks! but now it gives me this error : createError.js:16 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 502.  The first time that i loaded the react application it gives me the result of the query but then it gives me this error : / .
On react application i have axios.get("/get")  and in the index.js of the server i have app.get("/get").

Comment: Solved it ! I have missed to put the port of the proxy pass.Now it works ! Thanks !